# Convert Ruby hash to Json in C#

Tags: c#, json, ruby

I'm looking for help to write a method to convert Ruby hash to Json in C#.

FYI A Ruby hash is like this:

```
{"tiger"=>3, "lion"=>2, "dog"=>2, "cat"=>3}
```

But can also contains array like this

```
{"section"=>"Gar", "code"=>2, "collections"=>"[{:key=>\"emotion\", :value=>\"Emotion\"}]", "batch"=>"M"}
```

I know it is very easy to convert a Ruby hash to Json with the to_json instruction in Ruby but I'm looking for similar instruction in C# (if exist).

In other word I receive a string in this format:

```
{"section"=>"Gar", "code"=>2, "collections"=>"[{:key=>\"emotion\", :value=>\"Emotion\"}]", "batch"=>"M"}
```

and I want this

```
{"section": "Gar", "code": 2, "batch": "M", "collections": [{"key": "emotion", "value": "Emotion"}]}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. When you say "Ruby hash," do you mean, perhaps, a string that contains Ruby hash syntax?

Comment: Yes but in Ruby it's not really a string... well in the database it is save as something else than a string (hstore) so I just tried to avoid using the word "string" to avoid confusion. It seems that it create confusion actually. Sorry I'm not Ruby developer.

Comment: You didn't mention a database in your question. It would be helpful if you could back up a bit. Where does this data come from? How does your program receive or retrieve it?

Comment: We don't care. I actually receive this string from a C# web API from a ruby client. I receive it as a string. Normally I must receive a json string but sometime I receive this ruby hash string. I can deserialize json data but not this ruby hash format. But I find that stupid to reject this string because I think I can easely transform it to json because a ruby hash is just another format to write something very similar to json.

Comment: Ok. The question is, or can be reas as "is there something similar to to_json in C#?"

Comment: "a ruby hash is just another format to write something very similar to json" What you've shown is not "just another format," it's Ruby *code*. Ruby code is not a generic data serialization format. Short of writing your own Ruby parser—or invoking `ruby`—there is not a reliable way to parse Ruby code in C#. If a third-party API is occasionally (but not always) sending you Ruby code instead of JSON then it's a problem with the API and you should contact the API vendor, as you're probably not the only user for whom this is a problem.

Comment: So I can start by creating a method that replace the => by : and remove the \ but after this this become more complicate.

Comment: I receive this string in my API from Ruby developer for for me this is a string... Ah you are a ruby developer. So I think you cannot help me because my question is more about C#. And no I don't use an API I m the API.

Comment: It would be strange if there was built-in method to convert ruby hash to json in c#. So you have to write it yourself I guess.

Comment: If there is the native `to_json` in ruby, couldn't you ask the Ruby developer to send you the json instead?

Comment: @Evk Agree but who knows. Maube this format is more than just Ruby hash. Now after comment of Jordan I realize this is very specific to Ruby only. So I will write my method and post my solution here for the community.

Comment: Talk to the developer and tell them you're not using Ruby so you can't parse Ruby, and ask them to provide a way for you to get JSON instead. There's a reason other languages don't know how to parse Ruby: We have great, well-documented, standardized data serialization formats like JSON already, and every major platform knows how to both generate and parse that data.

Comment: I guess simple replace will not work, because these symbols might appear inside values. I'd agree with others - returning ruby hash from web api is quite a bad idea.

Comment: @Magnetron Yes of course this is the first think I will ask now. But again if this hash is a common format and something exist or is easy to do I will do it.

Comment: I just try to ease the work of these Ruby developer that send me this hash data in place of correct API :-) But I will do as you suggest.

Comment: You should ask the ruby dev to just pass the hash to you using the `.to_json` syntax. That's the correct way, since the code is interacting with other languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a dirty but working alternative by replacing element of my string by others step by step. It works perfectly.

```
// Define other methods and classes here
public string ToJson(string hash)
{
    hash = Regex.Replace(hash, @":(\w+)=>", @"""$1"": ");
    hash = Regex.Replace(hash, @"\\""", @"""");
    hash = Regex.Replace(hash, @"\\\\", @"");
    hash = Regex.Replace(hash, @"=>", @": ");
    hash = Regex.Replace(hash, @"""\[", @"[");
    hash = Regex.Replace(hash, @"\]""", @"]");
    hash = Regex.Replace(hash, @"""\{", @"{");
    hash = Regex.Replace(hash, @"\}""", @"}");
    hash = Regex.Replace(hash, @"NULL", @"null");
    hash = $"{{{hash}}}";
    //JObject jObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(hash);
    return hash;
}
```